# How to detect if a syscall exists on linux programmatically?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I am trying to compile a C program that will be run on some older version of kernel. The kernel where I compile the program is not the same version as the kernel version where my program will be run.
If I call a syscall that only on newer version of kernel, will the program crash, or return a error value?

Comment: perhaps use the kernel headers for the apropriate kernel version

Comment: `man 2 intro` might be useful for you, as a supplement to @Wintermute's answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends. It is rather rare that system calls are invoked directly (the `syscalls (2)` man page even makes note of this); it is more common to use library wrappers such as `write`, `read`, `open`, `close` and others. If you attempt to to use a wrapper function for a syscall that doesn't exist on the system in question, it is likely that the wrapper also does not exist, in which case your program will not get past the runtime linker and fail to start.

If, on the other hand, you invoke system calls (more or less) directly through the `syscall` function, e.g.

```
syscall(SYS_write, fd, buffer, size);
```

instead of

```
write(fd, buffer, size);
```

then `syscall` will return `-1` if you attempt to invoke a nonexistent system call, and `errno` will be set to `ENOSYS`.

If you use a `libc` that is new enough to contain the wrapper function with a kernel that is old enough to not support the corresponding system call, the wrapper function will probably hand down this error. Check the documentation of the wrapper function in question.